# How can get following column pattern of a list with CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, multiple-columns

I need to arrange my list in columns in the following pattern

Columns : 4

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>



 ---------------------
    1  3  4  5
    2
    ---------------------
    1  3  5  6
    2  4
    -----------------------
    1  4  7  9
    2  5  8  10
    3  6  
   -----------------------
    1  5  9  13
    2  6  10 14
    3  7  11 15
    4  8  12
```

Can anyone provide a quick solution?

Comment: CSS columns will be your solution.

Comment: Don't be so sure Terry

Comment: @JohnWink How many `<li>` elements will you have maximum? Unknown? As it stands your current layout doesn't make sense unless the maximum is 8, but your code and example don't describe a maximum. In other words, it's unclear how you expect this to scale beyond 8.

Comment: @TylerH: Thanks for showing interest in my question. I know that my requirement is little odd, but I need this to survive one of my requirements. There is no maximum limit. 

I need it in some way to avoid layout change. I can do this with some javascript. If I will not find a solution in CSS.

Thanks everyone for your valuable time and efforts.

Comment: @JohnWink Okay, thanks. So if you have 9 `<li>` elements, how would you expect them to show up? Essentially, the way you have the `<li>` elements ordered doesn't make sense (fill two rows on the first column, then one row on the 3rd, 4th, and 5th column). Typically when you have a column-number requirement, you fill the `<li>` elements left-to-right first. That way the code can handle an unlimited number programmatically, e.g. "fill four columns, then go to a new row. Rinse and repeat". But you seem to want "fill one column for two rows, then fill one row for the rest of the three columns".

Comment: @TylerH: THANKS, I just added 2 more examples with more no of items, Can you please check, if still not able to find the pattern, I will explain you.

Comment: @JohnWink I'm starting to see (I think) but in the third example, why isn't `9` in row 3, column 3?

Comment: @TylerH: bcoz, remaining items should hang horizontally, not vertically.
The last row should contain item count of the remainder of column count(4).

Comment: This is not possible with CSS and column-count....or any other layout method. I suggest you re-think your requirements.

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D, I understood. Anyway, I'm doing with javascript.

Comment: and why you don't share your JS code so we can see how it works ?

Answer (score 0):

**CSS-Grid**...but it's not scalable or dynamic in my opinion as it stands.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  width: 50%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

ul:nth-of-type(1) li:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: 2;
}

ul:nth-of-type(2) li:nth-child(2),
ul:nth-of-type(2) li:nth-child(4) {
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I appreciate @Paulie_D for your valuable time and efforts. But it will not survive my purpose.

Comment: See the comments under the OP @Paulie_D, I don't quite follow but maybe it'll make sense to you?

Answer (score -2):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox*** if you take advantage of the `order` property:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  flex: 0 1 25%;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  order: 1; /* second last */
}

li:nth-child(4) {
  order: 2; /* last */
}

/* initial value of the order property is set to 0 */
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you try your column technique?

Comment: am not the asker ;)

Comment: Haha yes delete your col count answer as i thought

Comment: check his pattern

Comment: I am looking. If he wants the top one he can delete 1 li. The 2nd example is exact

Comment: Stefan, he wants the li elements to display vertically 2 at a time. 1, then 2 below. Not 1, then 2 to the side.

Comment: Wait he changed to vertical i swear!

Comment: Well touche. I tried col count first and ran into same problem you did

Comment: I appreciate @StefanBob & others for your valuable time and efforts. But it will not survive my purpose.